# Не могу завершить процесс

Tags: c#

Не могу закрыть процесс `cmd1`. Пытался после строки `buffer = sr1.ReadToEnd();` прописать `process.Kill()` или `processs.Close()` — всё то же самое. Есть какие-то идеи?

P.S. `cmd` — путь к батнику, `cl` — путь до рабочей директории, `outname` — имя выходного файла, `param` — параметры запуска.

```
var cmd1 = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = @"/k """ + cmd + @"""",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    // RedirectStandardError = true
    WorkingDirectory = cl
};

var process = Process.Start(cmd1);
StreamReader sr1 = process.StandardOutput;
using (StreamWriter sr = process.StandardInput)
{
    if (sr.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        sr.WriteLine(@"cl " + outname + @".cpp " + param);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
        buffer = sr1.ReadToEnd();

    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте перед завершением процесса закрыть его поток вывода `sr1` — возможно, он и держит процесс.

Comment: @Arhad пытался закрыть, не работает.

Comment: @DenisBubnov sr.WriteLine(@"cl " + outname + @".cpp " + param) имеете в виду это?

Comment: @DenisBubnov, все равно не получается. Вызываю KillProcessAndChildrens(process.Id), где process имя моего процесса

Comment: Думаю, стоит делать это после закрытия `StreamWriter` ну или хотя бы почитать про `StandardOutput` хотя бы тут: [Process.StandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.90).aspx) обратите внимание на раздел *Заметки*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы запускаете командную строку, а в ней запускаете что-то еще в виде дочернего процесса, насколько я понимаю. Чтобы завершить процесс, вам необходимо завершить все его дочерние процессы. Пример с использованием WMI (необходимо подключить пространство имен `System.Management`):

```
private static void KillProcessAndChildrens(int pid)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher processSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
      ("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + pid);
    ManagementObjectCollection processCollection = processSearcher.Get();

    try
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        if (!proc.HasExited) proc.Kill();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        // Process already exited.
    }

    if (processCollection != null)
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in processCollection)
        {
            // kill child processes(also kills childrens of childrens etc.)
            KillProcessAndChildrens(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"])); 
        }
    }
}
```

Ссылка на источник: [`Process.Kill()` doesn't seem to kill the process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30313207/5275890)

Также следует обратить внимание на то, что вы используете и что пытаетесь сделать. Конкретно, я говорю про свойство [Process.StandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.90).aspx), следует обратить внимание на некоторые нюансы из данной ссылки:

> Перенаправленный поток `StandardOutput` может считываться синхронно или
>   асинхронно. Такие методы как `Read`, `ReadLine` и `ReadToEnd` выполняют
>   операции синхронного считывания в потоке вывода процесса. Эти операции
>   синхронного считывания не завершаются, пока связанный `Process` не
>   запишет в свой поток `StandardOutput` или не закроет поток.
>
> В противовес этому, `BeginOutputReadLine` запускает операции асинхронного считывания
>   в потоке `StandardOutput`. Этот метод включает маршрутизируемый
>   обработчик событий вывода потока и сразу возвращается вызывающему
>   объекту, который может выполнять другую работу, пока вывод потока
>   направлен обработчику событий.
>
> Операции синхронного считывания
>   представляют зависимость между считыванием вызывающего объекта из
>   потока `StandardOutput` и записью дочернего процесса в этот поток. Эти
>   зависимости могут приводить к условиям взаимоблокировки. Если
>   вызывающий объект считывает из перенаправленного потока дочернего
>   процесса, он зависит от дочернего элемента. Вызывающий объект ожидает
>   операции считывания до тех пор, пока дочерний элемент записывает в
>   поток или закрывает поток. Когда дочерний процесс записывает
>   достаточно данных для заполнения своего перенаправленного потока, он
>   зависит от родительского элемента. Дочерний процесс ожидает следующей
>   операции записи до тех пор, пока родительский элемент считывает из
>   полного потока или закрывает поток. Условие взаимоблокировки приводит
>   к тому, что в то время, когда вызывающий объект и дочерний процесс
>   ожидают друг друга для завершения операции, ни один из них не может
>   продолжить работу. Взаимоблокировок можно избежать оценивая
>   зависимости между вызывающим объектом и дочерним процессом.

Также, там имеется следующий пример, в котором демонстрируется считывание из перенаправленного потока и ожидание завершения дочернего процесса:

```
// Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();

 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();

 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Думаю, что проблема в этом. Внимательно прочтите раздел *Заметки*, имеются нюансы, в силу которых у вас не выходит завершить поток.